# VBA Userform - force list change

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Useform which shows a list, see picture, i have forced the userform to always begin by having `ComboBox1.text = "Please Select Item"`.

However, how do i force the user to actually select an item before hitting the `Ok` Button??
My understanding is that i'll use a ComboBox1_BeforeUpdate sub - however, can't figure out the details.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On activation i disable the OK button

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

OK.Enabled = False

...

End Sub
```

Then on Change i reactivate the button

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If ComboBox1.Text <> "Please Select Item" Then
        OK.Enabled = True
    Else
        OK.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```